# One simple 'if' statement in Julia increases the run-time of my prime sieve by a factor of 15 – why?

Tags: if-statement, runtime, julia

I've been experimenting with various prime sieves in Julia with a view to finding the fastest. This is my simplest, if not my fastest, and it runs in around 5-6 ms on my 1.80 GHz processor for n = 1 million. However, when I add a simple 'if' statement to take care of the cases where n <= 1 or s (the start number) > n, the run-time increases by a factor of 15 to around 80-90 ms.

```
using BenchmarkTools

function get_primes_1(n::Int64, s::Int64=2)::Vector{Int64}
    #=if n <= 1 || s > n
        return []
    end=#
    sieve = fill(true, n)
    for i = 3:2:isqrt(n) + 1
        if sieve[i]
            for j = i ^ 2:i:n
                sieve[j]= false
            end
        end
    end
    pl = [i for i in s - s % 2 + 1:2:n if sieve[i]]
    return s == 2 ? unshift!(pl, 2) : pl
end

@btime get_primes_1(1_000_000)
```

Output with the 'if' statement commented out, as above, is:

```
5.752 ms (25 allocations: 2.95 MiB)
```

Output with the 'if' statement included is:

```
86.496 ms (2121646 allocations: 35.55 MiB)
```

I'm probably embarrassingly ignorant or being terminally stupid, but if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem of this function is with Julia compiler having problems with type inference when closures appear in your function. In this case the closure is a comprehension and the problem is that `if` statement makes `sieve` to be only conditionally defined.

You can see this by moving `sieve` up:

```
function get_primes_1(n::Int64, s::Int64=2)::Vector{Int64}
    sieve = fill(true, n)
    if n <= 1 || s > n
        return Int[]
    end
    for i = 3:2:isqrt(n) + 1
        if sieve[i]
            for j = i ^ 2:i:n
                sieve[j]= false
            end
        end
    end
    pl = [i for i in s - s % 2 + 1:2:n if sieve[i]]
    return s == 2 ? unshift!(pl, 2) : pl
end
```

However, this makes `sieve` to be created also when `n<1` which you want to avoid I guess :).

You can solve this problem by wrapping `sieve` in `let` block like this:

```
function get_primes_1(n::Int64, s::Int64=2)::Vector{Int64}
    if n <= 1 || s > n
        return Int[]
    end
    sieve = fill(true, n)
    for i = 3:2:isqrt(n) + 1
        if sieve[i]
            for j = i ^ 2:i:n
                sieve[j]= false
            end
        end
    end
    let sieve = sieve
        pl = [i for i in s - s % 2 + 1:2:n if sieve[i]]
        return s == 2 ? unshift!(pl, 2) : pl
    end
end
```

or avoiding an inner closure for example like this:

```
function get_primes_1(n::Int64, s::Int64=2)::Vector{Int64}
    if n <= 1 || s > n
        return Int[]
    end
    sieve = fill(true, n)
    for i = 3:2:isqrt(n) + 1
        if sieve[i]
            for j = i ^ 2:i:n
                sieve[j]= false
            end
        end
    end
    pl = Int[]
    for i in s - s %2 +1:2:n
        sieve[i] && push!(pl, i)
    end
    s == 2 ? unshift!(pl, 2) : pl
end
```

Now you might ask how can you detect such problems and make sure that some solution solves them? The answer is to use `@code_warntype` on a function. In your original function you will notice that `sieve` is `Core.Box` which is an indication of the problem.

See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15276 for details. In general this is in my perception the most important issue with performance of Julia code which is easy to miss. Hopefully in the future the compiler will be smarter with this.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's really helpful. All these methods reduce the run-time to close to the original. I actually do use `@code_warntype` as a matter of routine, but it can be difficult for we amateurs to interpret what we're seeing. Sometimes it's obvious, sometimes less so. For example, even with the changes you suggest, I'm still getting a temporary variable with the `Any` type (specifically `#temp#@_18::ANY`). I'm not sure what this is, how to correct it, or whether it's even an issue.

Comment: This is a negligible issue. You get it only with generator versions (so the last one that uses loop does not have this problem). The issue is that for `[i for i in s - s % 2 + 1:2:n if sieve[i]]` Julia is not able to identify type because the generator might create an empty collection. To solve this you would have to write `Int[i for i in s - s % 2 + 1:2:n if sieve[i]]`. But - as was discussed in thread by @DNF - this does not matter much, because this type instability does not affect internal computations and the function converts its output to `Vector{Int}` anyway following the signature.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I've actually used your non-generator version in my current code, and my prime sieves are flying. My one-third sieve is running in just under 3 ms for n = 1 million, which I'm more than happy with.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** My suggestion actually doesn't seem to help. I missed your output annotation, so the return type appears to be correctly inferred after all. I am stumped, for the moment.

**Original answer:**

The problem isn't that there is an `if` statement, but that you introduce a type instability inside that `if` statement. You can read about type instabilities in the performance section of the Julia manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/performance-tips/#Write-%22type-stable%22-functions-1).

An empty array defined like this: `[]`, has a different type than a vector of integers:

```
> typeof([1,2,3])
Array{Int64,1}

> typeof([])
Array{Any,1}
```

The compiler cannot predict what the output type of the function will be, and therefore produces defensive, slow code.

Try to change

```
return []
```

to

```
return Int[]
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with Performance Tips so I'm usually pretty strict about my type definitions. Indeed, when I define the function above I define the return type, so I think Julia does indeed infer the correct type from the empty array. When I run the function for n = 1 it returns `Int64[0]`.

Comment: See the explanation of the problem in my answer which is a completely different issue. But given this thread - it is marginally better to use `Int[]` than `[]` in the first return statement as what Julia does in your original code it takes an empty `Vector{Any}` and converts it to an empty `Vector{Int}`. You can avoid it by simply returing `Int[]`.